# Why does my code sometimes set a value of 0 and loop forever?

Tags: java

I need to program a attack value for a Pokemon fight. and then I need to multiply the damage value with a number between 0 and 1, after each round, but sometimes my damage value is 0 and then it goes on forever.

How can I fix this?

the if case at the end was a try to fix the problem.

```
 public static void attackvalue(Taschenmonster pokemon1, Taschenmonster pokemon2) {

    double multiplier = Math.random();

    pokemon1.damage = (int) (pokemon1.damage * multiplier);
    pokemon2.damage = (int) (pokemon2.damage * multiplier);

    if (pokemon1.damage <= 45){
        pokemon1.damage = (int) (pokemon1.damage * multiplier);
    }
    if (pokemon2.damage <= 45){
        pokemon2.damage = (int) (pokemon2.damage * multiplier);
    }

}
```

Comment: The way the actual pokemon games do it is, after all damage calculation, if damage dealt is less than 1, it's increased to 1. You could do something similar, like `pokemon1.damage = Math.max(pokemon1.damage, 1)`.

Comment: I think you need to be more specific with what you want your algorithm to be.  As described, ending up as 0 is completely reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue

The following operation: `pokemon1.damage * multiplier` gives you a double value, if you are unlucky enough, it might results in a value in the range: [0, 1[.

Then, you are converting this value into an integer using the `(int) ...`. This truncates away the floating part, therefore any value between 0 and 1 (excluded) are changed to 0.

#### Solution

To avoid this scenario, you should clamp your value in a given range, e.g.

`pokemon1.damage = Math.max(10, Math.min(100, pokemon1.damage));`

But the idea behind your attempt is the same, but should be more like:

```java
if (pokemon1.damage <= 45){
        pokemon1.damage = 45;
    }
```

Setting value to 45 instead of re-doing the same computation as before.

Comment: How can I fix this ? The Damage value needs to be an integer but I need to multiply it with a double

Comment: it is actually the correct way to do it, your only issue is that you do not bound the possible values. Setting a minimum boundary as you attempted (e.g. 45) should fix your issue

Comment: But the problem is when i say it will be 45 when its lower, then it will be 45 until the end because after this it will always be lower than 45.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `(int)`, it rounds your value towards `0`.

If the variable `damage` in `Taschenmonster` is an `int`, change it to a `double` so that it can store floating point values (like `2.7`)

Edit:

Use `Math.round(...)` instead of `(int) ...` so that if your damage results in `0.6`, it will be stored as `1`